# How to persist and load NSDatePicker date values

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

I am very new to MacOs development so apologies if this is a simplistic question:

I have an app that stores and loads data to an SQlite db.

A view has an NSDatePicker in graphic mode and the view can be either in 'add' or 'edit' mode ie adding or retrieving and updating data from SQlite

Another view has an NSTableView where one of the columns is the date that I want to load from SQlite into the column.

My question is what property of the datePicker should I persist - datePicker.stringValue or datepicker.dateValue?

If it is .stringValue can I simply load this when displaying the datePicker on the 'edit' view?

If it is .dateValue how do I get the value for the tableView? (use NSDateFormatter?)

SQlite does not have a date type so I am using a text field to store the date

Comment: How do you use the date? Which date and time elements are displayed by the picker? Which date format do you store in the database?

Comment: Adding a `NSDateFormatter` to the text field in the table view in the storyboard/XIB will make the object value of the text field a date.

Comment: I have no code written yet. The date will be used to display in a tableview column. I only want to show the date in the column not the time. In the SQlite database I am using the Text storage class as SQlite does not have a date storage class. I want the date to display in the table view as something like 3rd Jan 2018, but I need to be able to re-load the stored date from Sqlite into the datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting dates back and forth to string is messy and somewhat fragile. I suggest saving it as a floating point value instead.

To convert a date to a Double use:

```
let interval = aDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

(Where `aDate` is a `Date` object, and `interval` is a Double, a.k.a a `TimeInterval`)

Conversely, to convert a floating point value back to a `Date`:

```
let aDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: interval)
```

You should be able to save the resulting `interval` floating-point value to your SQL database. Use Double precision for the floating point value.

Comment: Thanks very much that makes sense. Will try that out

Comment: Have tried this and it works great. Thanks for the answer

Comment: If my answer helped you you should accept it. That way other readers know which answer resolves somebody's problem.

Comment: Done that now. Didnt realise as new to Stack Overflow

Comment: It's also considered good form to up-vote answers you find helpful, although that's entirely up to you.